# Getting com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found when inserting content under load

Tags: c#, .net, marklogic, ikvm

We are using the Marklogic XCC .Net library for inserting documents into Marklogic. However under load (45 concurrent users), we start getting the exception with the message Provider **com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found**
Does somebody have a clue ?

The code is

```
using (var session = ContentSourceFactory.NewContentSource(new Uri(_connectionUriString)).NewSession())
        {

                var contentCreateOptions = new ContentCreateOptions
                                               {
                                                   Format = DocumentFormat.Format.XML,
                                                   Collections =
                                                       new[]
                                                           {
                                                            "Docs"
                                                           }
                                               };
                var options = contentCreateOptions;
                var fileName = string.Format("/doc/{0}.xml", doc.Id);
                session.InsertContent(ContentFactory.NewContent(fileName, doc.Serialize(), options));
            }
```

Comment: I suspect you'll get better traction if you post this directly to the marklogic developer list at http://community.marklogic.com/mailman/listinfo/general

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is not being caused by your code itself. More likely the server is running out of memory, causing it to fail to load necessary classes/objects to run the code. Trim down the number of allowed parallel requests, or increase memory.

HTH!